# getting a servlet to print from a csv file to an xhtml page/PluginExecutionException

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, java-ee-7

I need to pull data from a csv file that is on my computer and print it to a web page via a servlet. The data needs to read one line at a time and refresh every second, then when it hits the end of the csv file, start again at the top. I feel like I'm close, but when I try to build the program nothing outputs to the web page. It's highly possible that something is misplaced in the code. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated, I completely suck at programming and am just trying to get through this class. I have added code from all 3 parts. I am using netbeans IDE 8.2 and glassfish server.

```
main.xthml:


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Ivan's HTTP ETF</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/default.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var ajaxRequest;
      function updatePage() {
          if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
              var arraypv = ajaxRequest.responseText.split("/");
              document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = arraypv[0];
              document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = arraypv[1];
              document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = arraypv[2];
              document.getElementById("volume").innerHTML = arraypv[3];
              document.getElementById("52-weekHigh").innerHTML = arraypv[4];
              document.getElementById("52-weekLow").innerHTML = arraypv[5];
              makeAjaxRequest();
          }
      }
      function makeAjaxRequest() {
          ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
          ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/dukeetf/dukeetf", true);
          ajaxRequest.send(null);
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="makeAjaxRequest();">
    <h1>Ivan's HTTP ETF</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Ticker</td>
            <td align="right">IGH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Date</td>
            <td id="date" align="right">--</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Time</td>
            <td id="time" align="right">--</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Price</td>
            <td id="price" align="right">--</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Volume</td>
            <td id="volume" align="right">--</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">52-weekHigh</td>
            <td id="weekHigh" align="right">--</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">52-weekLow</td>
            <td id="weekLow" align="right">--</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
DukeETFServlet.java:

package javaeetutorial.web.dukeetf;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.AsyncEvent;
import javax.servlet.AsyncListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/dukeetf"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class DukeETFServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DukeETFServlet");
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2114153638027156979L;

    private Queue<AsyncContext> requestQueue;
    @EJB private PriceVolumeBean pvbean; 

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        /* Queue for requests */
        requestQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        /* Register with the bean that provides price/volume updates */
        pvbean.registerServlet(this);
    }

    /* PriceVolumeBean calls this method every second to send updates */
    public void send(String date, String time, String price, String volume, String weekHigh, String weekLow) {
        /* Send update to all connected clients */
        requestQueue.forEach((acontext) -> {
            try {
                String msg = String.format(date, time, price, volume, weekHigh, weekLow);
                PrintWriter writer = acontext.getResponse().getWriter();
                writer.write(msg);
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {0}", msg);
                /* Close the connection
                * The client (JavaScript) makes a new one instantly */
                acontext.complete();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, ex.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    /* Service method */
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        /* Put request in async mode. */
        final AsyncContext acontext = request.startAsync();
        /* Remove from the queue when done */
        acontext.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AsyncEvent ae) throws IOException {
                requestQueue.remove(acontext);
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection closed.");
            }
            @Override
            public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent ae) throws IOException {
                requestQueue.remove(acontext);
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection timeout.");
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(AsyncEvent ae) throws IOException {
                requestQueue.remove(acontext);
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection error.");
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent ae) throws IOException { }
        });
        /* Add to the queue */
        requestQueue.add(acontext);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection open.");
    }
}
```

```
PriceVolumeBean.java:

package javaeetutorial.web.dukeetf;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/* Updates price and volume information every second */
@Startup
@Singleton
public class PriceVolumeBean {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("PriceVolumeBean");
  private final String csvFile = "/Users/ivanhurdimac/glassfish5/docs/javaee-tutorial/examples/web/servlet/dukeetf/project4input.csv";

  /* Use the container's timer service */
  @Resource TimerService tservice;

  private BufferedReader reader = null;
  private DukeETFServlet servlet;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    try {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read the CSV file [" + csvFile + "].", e);
    }

    /* Intialize the EJB and create a timer */
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Initializing EJB.");
    tservice.createIntervalTimer(1000, 1000, new TimerConfig());
  }

  public void registerServlet(DukeETFServlet servlet) {
    /* Associate a servlet to send updates to */
    this.servlet = servlet;
  }

  @Timeout
  public void timeout() {

    String line;
    try {
      line = reader.readLine();

      // Once we are done, just return
      if (line == null) {
        return;
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read a line from the CSV file [" + csvFile + "].", e);
      } finally {
        if (reader != null){
            try{
                reader.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
             throw new RuntimeException("CSV file didn't close [" + csvFile + "].", e);   
            }
        }   
        }

    String[] parts = line.split(",");

    /* Adjust price and volume and send updates */
    String date = parts[0];
    String time = parts[1];
    String price = parts[2];
    String volume = parts[3];
    String weekHigh = parts[4];
    String weekLow = parts[5];

    if (servlet != null) {
      servlet.send(date, time, price, volume, weekHigh, weekLow);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should always include the full stacktrace in your question with version information in used modules and a [mcve]

Comment: I made the edit, is that what you meant?